# In python, downloading html file and store in a file

Tags: python, unicode, request

I'm using python to download a html file and store in a file.
Here's the code:

```
url = "http://www.nytimes.com/roomfordebate/2014/09/24/protecting-student-privacy-in-online-learning"
page = requests.get(url) 
# save html content
file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
text_file = open(file_name, 'w+')
text_file.write(page.text())
text_file.close()
```

i got the following error:
File "scraper.py", line 15, in scrape_Page
    text_file.write(page.text())
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Could anyone tell how could I successfully store the text or why I got this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.text` is an *attribute*, not a method. You should not call it. You should not be using it to download a file, either, you should be using `.content` instead; you want the *undecoded bytes*, not the decoded Unicode value:

```
text_file.write(page.content)
```

To download content, you may want to stream it to the file instead:

```
import requests
import shutil

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
file_name = url.rpartition('/')[-1]
with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    r.raw.decode_content = True
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```